# Addressing oneself as "it" when one's gender is obvious

Tags: pronouns

I learnt that the word *it* can be used to refer a person whenever his/her gender is not known, for example: when someone is knocking the door or on a phone call etc. But look at the picture below, it's a Youtube video and the Youtuber addresses herself as *it* when her gender is obviously showing:

> It's Zoë from the Scratch team

If I were the person, I would say *I'm Zoe*. Is it okay to use *it* like this?

[image]

Comment: See randomhead's answer for the direct answer to the question. I should add, though: The topic of gender and pronouns is fraught, but current practice  encourages "they" (even for singular usages) as a gender-neutral choice. In English, "it" can suggest an inanimate object ("I'm not an 'it'!"). And if one is sensitive to questions of gender, one should not suppose that it "obviously shows."

Comment: @Andy Bonner If it's the case as you mentioned, how can I know what gender he/she is before he/she explicitly tells me? So what personal pronoun should I use to talk with this person?

Comment: That's the point, exactly. You can ask directly, "what pronouns do you prefer?" Unfortunately, that may also cause offense with some people. But the point is that biological sex and gender are two different ideas, and the idea that "gender is obvious" would find strong disagreement from some (and strong agreement from others).

Comment: @preachers - If you're talking with this person, the appropriate pronoun (for all genders) is "you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> I learnt that the word *it* can be used to refer a person whenever his/her gender is not known, for example: when someone is knocking the door or on a phone call etc

This is not quite right. First of all, as Andy Bonner mentioned in a comment, you would use either the "generic *he*"<sup>1</sup> or "singular *they*" when referring to a person of unknown gender; "it" is generally used for inanimate objects and sometimes animals, so when you use "it" as a personal pronoun referring to a human you can sound quite rude.

But more importantly than that, the "it" used in sentences like:

> Who is **it**?
> **It**'s the pizza man!

is **not** being used as a personal pronoun like *he/she/they*! Instead it is a [*dummy **it***](https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414) or [*introductory **it***](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/introductory-it). From the first link, a definition of a *dummy **it***:

> Unlike the ordinary pronoun *it*, dummy *it* refers to nothing at all; it simply serves a grammatical function. In other words, dummy *it* has a grammatical meaning but no lexical meaning.

This YouTuber is using the dummy *it* in exactly the same way as the examples above. She is *not* using it as a personal pronoun to "address herself;" she is using it to introduce the person who is speaking (which happens to be herself in this case). To see how "it" is *not* being used as a personal pronoun, consider this exchange:

> **Person A:** Who is the person who is speaking?
> **Person B:** It is *Zoë from the Scratch team* who is speaking.

Person B could have used the personal pronoun "she" to replace "Zoë from the Scratch team" *and they still would have used the introductory **it***:

> **Person B:** It is *she* who is speaking.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or the "generic *she*" as some writers have taken to doing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you mean that the sentence "It's Zoë from the Scratch team" was not the full version? It should have been "It's Zoë from the Scratch team speaking" and the unusual used version might have been "Zoë from the Scratch team is speaking"?

Comment: @preachers no, that was just for illustration. You could imagine that "It is X" is short for "It is X who is here/speaking/blue/cold/*any other adjective*" if that helps you understand, but the short version is perfectly natural and stands on its own.

Comment: It's just the same as your example of 'someone knocking at the door'. "Who is it?" "It's me, Zoë."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yeah, that's what really confused me, because I can see the person in the video, there should be a difference from the _door knocking situation_. But maybe _Andy Bonner_ is right, I didn't think of that before.

Comment: @preachers As Kate said this is *exactly the same* as the "someone at the door" situation. There is no difference. In both situations both the gender of the person *and whether the gender is known* are completely irrelevant, because there is no personal pronoun in the sentence, **only** the dummy "it."

Comment: @randomhead Thanks, got it.

Comment: One more point on "how to choose the best gender-neutral language": If you're just talking, that's one thing, but if you're doing formal writing, many style manuals make specific recommendations (AP, Turabian, Chicago, etc.).

Comment: In your 2nd link, it said "'Introductory it' is used to give extra emphasis to the subject it introduces." The example is "Peter not John bought a new car. <-> It was Peter who bought a new car." Since the example shares the same structure as "It is Zoë from the Scratch team who is speaking." Dose the sentence also have the emphasis sense on it?

Comment: @preachers **no**, that is only one use of the introductory *it*. Using "it is..." to introduce a speaker carries no special emphasis.

Comment: @randomhead So the context is important here, right?

Comment: Yes, as in every other English sentence you will come across.